# When to specify a package name in use-package's :ensure tag?

Tags: package, use-package

`use-package` lets you automatically install packages by using the `:ensure` tag. You can do that as follows

```el
(use-package <package>
  :ensure t)
```

But for some packages that doesn't work, such as `auctex`. In those cases you can specify the package to `ensure` as follows

```el
(use-package tex
  :ensure auctex)
```

According to [this blog/tutorial/site](http://cachestocaches.com/2015/8/getting-started-use-package/), the reason is

> because, once installed, `auctex` overrides the `tex` package.

What does that mean and how can I tell when to do that for other packages?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> But for some packages that doesn't work. Such as `auctex`.

The reason `(use-package tex :ensure t)` doesn't work for `auctex` is because `auctex` names a GNU ELPA package (see [`(emacs) Packages`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Packages.html)), whereas `tex` names a feature (see [`(elisp) Named Features`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html)) provided by the `auctex` package.

In other words, `tex` names a single file `tex.el` which is distributed as part of the `auctex` package. Consider the following examples:

Typing <kbd>M-x</kbd>`pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`<kbd>RET</kbd> with point after

```el
(use-package tex
  :ensure t)
```

gives a form which boils down to

```el
(progn
  (use-package-ensure-elpa 'tex '(t) 'nil)
  (require 'tex nil t))
```

whereas doing the same with

```el
(use-package tex
  :ensure auctex)
```

effectively expands to

```el
(progn
  (use-package-ensure-elpa 'tex '(auctex) 'nil)
  (require 'tex nil t))
```

This illustrates the difference in purpose between the `NAME` argument to `use-package` and its `:ensure` keyword. The former declares which named feature the rest of the stanza pertains/defaults to, with exactly the same meaning as in `with-eval-after-load`; see [`(elisp) Hooks for Loading`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html).

The latter just asks for the given package(s) to be installed via the second argument to the function `use-package-ensure-elpa`, where `t` just means the package named by the current `NAME`. `use-package-ensure-elpa`, in turn, calls `package-install`; for details on this see [`(emacs) Package Installation`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Installation.html).

> According to this blog/tutorial/site the reason is
>
> > because, once installed, auctex overrides the tex package.
>
> What does that mean

Unfortunately, this is both wrong and misleading. "Overriding" usually refers to replacing or monkey-patching existing functionality, e.g. via [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html). When one package provides the same named feature as another, thus hiding the latter from Emacs load functions, this is called "shadowing".

The AUCTeX distribution overrides and extends various built-in TeX-related functionality, but it does not shadow any built-in libraries. You can confirm this by inspecting the result of <kbd>M-x</kbd>`list-load-path-shadows`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

A better authority is the `use-package` documentation itself: https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/#package-installation.

> how can I tell when to do that for other packages?

It depends both on how you want to group your `use-package` stanzas and the name of the corresponding package. For example, if you want to put all or most of your Org-related settings under a single `(use-package org ...)`, but want to use the `org-plus-contrib` distribution of Org instead of the built-in one, then you would write

```el
(use-package org
  :ensure org-plus-contrib
  ...)
```

You wouldn't write

```el
(use-package org-plus-contrib
  :ensure t
  ...)
```

because there is no file named `org-plus-contrib.el`, even if there is a package with the name `org-plus-contrib`. You similarly wouldn't write

```el
(use-package auctex
  :ensure t
  ...)
```

for the same reason - there is no named feature `auctex` (there *is* a file `auctex.el`, but it does not call `(provide 'auctex)`).

---

Note that none of these discrepancies/semantics are specific to `use-package`; these are all (powerful and useful) Emacs features which `use-package` can only go so far in abstracting.