# How to automatically install Auctex if certain package is unable to be activated on startup?

Tags: auctex, package, install

every time I git clone my configuration of Emacs into a new machine and start Emacs, there will be error message in Emacs:

```
error: Unable to activate package 'company-auctex'.
Required package 'auctex-11.87' is unavailable
```

I know I can fix this problem by `package-install` auctex manually, but is there a way that I can check if activating `company-auctex` package failed and then install `auctex` automatically?

Comment: Maybe it helps if you run `(unless (package-installed-p 'auctex '(11 87)) (package-install 'auctex))` in your init-file.

Comment: I did this, but it keeps saying the same error, and it won't install auctex. (BTW, the version of the auctex is not important).

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to a sliiiightly different approach, may I heartily recommend [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package)? Rather than "attempt to use, check for error, install if error," `use-package` will, on first install, check if the package exists *at all* and install it if needed. It's also effectively a deferred `require`, which can be very nice for managing package existence without bogging down loading.

This *does*, of course, mean you have to be sure `use-package` is installed properly, but the up-side is you only have to manually ensure a single package. I do this as @Tobias suggested, with an addition:

```
;; Be sure we've fetched the package archive at least once before
;; attempting to install anything.
(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))

;; Manually check for `use-package`, install if needed
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-install 'use-package))
```

Do note: in the case of `auctex` specifically, the `use-package` declaration takes a particular form:

```
(use-package tex
 :ensure auctex)
```

This is due to an idiosyncracy of `auctex` itself; see [this question and very thorough answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41321/when-to-specify-a-package-name-in-use-packages-ensure-tag) for details.

Comment: I know everyone is recommending `use-package`, and I've noticed this package and recommendations years ago, I've tried to use it several times, although it shouldn't be but it is really complicated to me, I don't fully understand how to use it for my init.el(my init.el is a mess) according the docs I've seen. And if I turn all my init.el into using `use-package`, that would be a lot of work. I'll consider your suggestion and may take a look at the `use-package` docs again and change my whole init.el once for all.

Comment: Very reasonable. It _can_ be used partially -- that is, you don't have to convert all-or-nothing. If usage examples are helpful, my emacs configs use `use-package` extensively: https://github.com/Gastove/orary/blob/master/init.el