# How to use `use-package` when the package and associated feature are named differently?

Tags: use-package

What `use-package` declaration should one use when the name of the package (as present in MELPA or GNU ELPA) and the name of the main `feature` provided by that package are different? For instance `wanderlust` provides the feature `wl` rather than `wanderlust`. As a consequence, neither of the following will work:

```
(use-package wl
  :ensure t)

(use-package wanderlust
  :ensure t)
```

Comment: Further googling provides this similar (duplicate?) question, with a very extensive answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41321/when-to-specify-a-package-name-in-use-packages-ensure-tag

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the answer is in `use-package`'s [manual/README](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/tree/60c81caac17e6a7ab5bd66df0c981b0530b51586#package-installation), though not too well explained:

> If you need to install a different package from the one named by use-package, you can specify it like this:
>
> ```
> (use-package tex
>   :ensure auctex)
> ```

Hence, in the case of `wanderlust` the solution would be:

```
(use-package wl
  :ensure wanderlust)
```